# Matrix Multiplication of 2 Pandas DF's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I have a 2 pandas dataframes that are (156915, 22) and (22,2) in shape. The DF1, (156915, 22), has column names that match DF2 column 1 rows. I want to do matrix multiplication where DF1.columns = DF2['col1']. Heres a quick view of what the df's may look like. I would like to return a pandas dataframe of the same shape as DF1. Thank you in advance!

```
DF1:

A | B  | C
1 | 15 | 8
5 | 3  | 2


DF2:

col1 | col2
A    | 5
B    | 1
C    | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

```
df3 = df2.set_index('col1')
df1[df3.index].apply(lambda x: x*df3['col2'].T,axis=1)`
```

Answer (score 1):

If your columns in `DF1` are in the same order as your `col1` in `DF2`, then using `np.dot` should work:

```
np.dot(DF1, DF2['col2'])
```

Comment: They are not in the same order unfortunately.

Comment: You could sort the columns in `DF1` by using `DF1.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)` and then sort `DF2` by `col1` using `DF2.sort_values('col1')`

Comment: Sorry I just made an edit but I want a pandas dataframe returned of the same size as DF1.

Comment: If you are using matrix multiplication, the returned dataframe will only be the same size as `DF1` if and only if the size of `DF2` is `(22,22)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!